# WebPack 2 - How to output to various other folders in the use/loader chains

Tags: webpack

First, the Webpack2 (2.3.3) Config Code:

```
//========== Imports =========================================================//

const path    = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

//========== Exports =========================================================//

module.exports = {

  entry: [
    "./src/js/main.js"
  ], // Entry //

  output: {
    path       : path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath : "/",
    filename   : "[name].bundle.js"
  }, // Output //

  module: {
    rules: [ { // [.tsx] TypeScript Loader //
      test    : /\.tsx$/,
      include : [path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/ts") ],
      use     : [ {
        loader : "ts-loader"
      }, {
        loader : "wc-loader"
      } ] // Use //
    }, { // [.html] WebComponent Loader //
      test    : /\.html$/,
      include : [path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/components") ],
      use     : [ {
        loader  : "babel-loader",
        options : {presets: [ ["es2015", {modules: false} ] ] }
      }, {
        loader : "wc-loader",
      } ] // Use //
    }, { // [.js] Javascript -> Babel Loader //
      test    : /\.js$/,
      include : [path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/js") ],
      exclude : [/node_modules/],
      use     : [ {
        loader  : "babel-loader",
        options : {presets: [ ["es2015", {modules: false} ] ] }
      }, {
        loader : "wc-loader"
      } ] // Use //
    }, { // [.png|.jpg|.gif|.svg] File Loader //
      test : /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
      use  : [ {
        loader : "file-loader"
      } ] // Use //
    }, { // [.scss] Sass Loader //
      test : /\.scss$/,
      use  : [ {
        loader : "sass-loader"
      } ] // Use //
    } ] // Rules //
  } // Module //

};
```

Is there a way set output folders per loader chain? (Javascript to go in one directory, Images to go in another, etc.)

Like providing it in the "options" in the "use"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using ExtractText plugin to split the fonts and css for WebPack 2 .. Didn't work well with "css-loader" (error) so I just passed it from "sass-loader" right to "raw-loader" instead of through "css-loader" :)